# jQuery: Check whether val() has a specific value or not upon form submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to check whether val() has a specific value or not inside a form, if so deleting the contents / preventing the form being submitted depending on if both fields are filled in (stringOne and stringTwo). There's a default text for each input field, the first being "Namn, telefonnr, sökord" and the second "Område, plats, ort". If a user only fills in the first field the second must be cleared before the form string is passed on and vice versa.
Like so -

```
// "This" refers to the form's submit button
if (($(this).siblings('input.stringOne').val("Namn, telefonnr, sökord")) && ($(this).siblings('input.stringTwo').val("Område, plats, ort"))) {
    return false; // If nothing's filled in, then do not submit
} else {
    // If either field is not filled in, clear it
    if ($(this).siblings('input.stringOne').val("Namn, telefonnr, sökord")) {
        $(this).siblings('input.stringOne').val() == '';
    }
    if ($(this).siblings('input.stringTwo').val("Område, plats, ort")) {
        $(this).siblings('input.stringTwo').val() == '';
    }
}
```

jQuery version 1.2.6.

Comment: jQuery version 1.2.6? Why? O.o

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's not possible to upgrade the site's scripts at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery, when you place a value inside `val()`, you are *setting* the value.

```
$('myElement').val()  // returns the value

$('myElement').val('some string')  // sets the value
```

`.val()` - http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
var $strOne = $(this).siblings('input.stringOne');
var $strTwo = $(this).siblings('input.stringTwo');

// "This" refers to the form's submit button
if ( (!$strOne.val() || $strOne.val() == "Namn, telefonnr, sökord") && (!$strTwo.val() || $strTwo.val() == "Område, plats, ort" ) {
    return false; // If nothing's filled in, then do not submit
} else {
    // If either field is not filled in, clear it
    if ($strOne.val() == "Namn, telefonnr, sökord") {
        $strOne.val("");
    }
    if ($strTwo.val() == "Område, plats, ort" ) {
        $strTwo.val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to come to that conclusion :) Tried checking against val() == '' also but it gave no results.

Comment: @Staffan - I'm a little confused by your use of `.siblings()`. Are there just 2 input fields, `.stringOne` and `.stringTwo`?

Comment: Patrick you're correct. Earlier I was referring to one single input field hence the use of siblings. I will remove them :)

Comment: @Staffan - I didn't notice that `$(this)` referred to the submit button (even though you stated it). Makes sense now.

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't work, remember there are already existing values in both fields (the default "Namn, telefonnr, sökord" and "Område, plats, ort").

Comment: @Staffan - The updated version tests if the `input` elements are empty, or if they have the default value.

Comment: It works! :) Thank you!
Not sure I understand why though, when I compare to an earlier script I did that used val() == '' as a checker on the input fields instead of variable placeholders, the end result should be the same?

Comment: Yes, the variable is not necessary. Just gives better performance. If you were doing `.val() == ""` as a test, it would work. In your question you were using `==` to assign the value inside the `if()` statement. And you were using `.val('someValue')` as the test, which actually assigns the value.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will be useful to someone:

This code

```
if ($('#my_text_field').val() == "Clear Me") {
    $('#my_text_field').val("");
```

Can be written

```
$('#my_text_field[value="Clear Me"]').val("");
```

Even better

```
$('#my_text_field[value="Clear Me"]').val("").change();
```

The .change() has the effect that $('#my_text_field[value="Clear Me"]') will not match #my_text_field after its value has changed